# What is the oxidation state of bromine in BrO3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, halides, oxidation-state

I came across this compound $\ce{BrO3}$ in my textbook, and was trying to find the oxidation state of bromine.

This is how I proceeded:

- Since this is not a superoxide or a peroxide, or any other case where the oxidation state of oxygen is not −2 according to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/oxidation-states-of-oxygen), so the oxidation state of oxygen should be −2.
- For oxidation state of Br as $x$, I can have $x + 3(-2) = 0$, which gives $x = +6$.

But, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oxidation_states_of_the_elements), the +6 oxidation state of Br is not listed.

I was confused because my book (NCERT Part I for class XII) says that "The bromine oxides Br2O, BrO2, BrO3 are the least stable halogen oxides (middle row anomaly) and exist only at low temperatures."

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

P. S. This is not an ion $(\ce{BrO3-})$ but a neutral compound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Bretherick’s Handbook of Reactive Chemical Hazards* lists bromine trioxide $\ce{BrO3}$ structure as the one composed of cationic and anionic parts [1, p. 116]:

> [image: structure of BrO3]
>
> The solid produced at $\pu{—5 °C}$ by interaction of bromine and ozone is only stable at $\pu{—80 °C}$ or in presence of ozone, and decomposition may be violently explosive in presence of trace impurities [...]. The structure may be the dimeric bromyl perbromate, analogous to $\ce{Cl2O6}$ [2].

so that formula written as $\ce{BrO3}$ is fine being a [formula unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_unit), but more correctly bromine trioxide should be written as $\ce{[BrO2]+[BrO4]-}$, implying that bromine is in two oxidation states: $+5$ and $+7$.

#### References

1. Bretherick, L.; Urben, P. G.; Pitt, M. J. Bretherick’s Handbook of Reactive Chemical Hazards, 7th ed.; *Elsevier: Amsterdam, The Netherlands ; Boston, MA*, **2007**. ISBN 978-0-12-373945-2.
2. Pflugmacher, A.; Rabben, H.-J.; Dahmen, H. Zur Kenntnis der Bromoxyde. Über das Bromtrioxyd. *Zeitschrift für anorganische und allgemeine Chemie* **1955**, 279 (5–6), 313–320. https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19552790507.